# Really exit Awk script

Tags: awk, scripting, exit

Perl and Ruby `exit` actually exits:

```
$ perl -e 'BEGIN {print 1; exit}; END {print 2}'
1

$ ruby -e 'BEGIN {print 1; exit}; END {print 2}'
1
```

Not so for Awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print 1; exit}; END {print 2}'
1
2
```

I tried to solve this with a "help.awk"

```perl
function really_exit() {
  IM_SURE = 1
  exit
}
END {
  if (IM_SURE) {
    exit
  }
}
```

but this creates its own problem. If "prog.awk" has only the begin block:

```perl
BEGIN {
  print "start"
}
```

Then running it:

```
awk -f help.awk -f prog.awk
```

will cause it to hang waiting for input. Is a better solution available, for
really exiting an Awk script?

Comment: Can ever the same `BEGIN` block be usefully used for both applications with and without input? If not, why not call `exit` from the `BEGIN` block?

Comment: Instead of using `exit` you can call `system()` and kill the `awk` process directly.

Comment: The `END` blocks are probably executed in the order in which they appear. So if your `BEGIN` block calls `exit` and the first `END` block (in your helper script) calls `exit` again then the "real" `END` blocks should not get executed.

Comment: seems a bug? `awk(1)` on my system says exit should "exit immediately" and nothing about going on to `END` blocks

Comment: The fact that END executes even after explicit exit is documented: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an Awk program has a "middle" or `END` block, then input is read. We can
counter this by providing null input:

```perl
$ cat prog.awk
1
END {
  print "fin"
}

$ awk -f prog.awk /dev/null
fin
```

If we want this to be the default, we can add a block to "help.awk":

```perl
BEGIN {
  if (ARGC == 1 && !system("[ -t 0 ]")) {
    ARGV[ARGC++] = "/dev/null"
  }
}
```

However this creates an important change; Awk will not read from terminal unless
you add a dash:

```
awk -f help.awk -f prog.awk -
```

or modify "prog.awk":

```perl
getline < "-"
```

Example reading input:

```perl
$ cat prog.awk
/4/ {
  really_exit()
}
1
END {
  print "fin"
}

$ seq 10 | awk -f help.awk -f prog.awk
1
2
3
```

Example not reading input:

```perl
$ cat prog.awk
BEGIN {
  print "start"
  really_exit()
}
END {
  print "fin"
}

$ awk -f help.awk -f prog.awk
start
```